# User input on subsequent images to store coordinates

Tags: image, matlab, figure

```
function main()
    clear all;clc;
    path='.\image_files\';  %___________image files path
    path_posmap='.\pos_maps\';%_________stores positions of agents
    NumOfImages = length(dir(path)) - 2;
    w = dir(path);
    img_names={};      %________stores names of all images
    for i=3:NumOfImages+2,
        img_names{i-2} = w(i).name;
    end

    for i=1:numel(img_names),
        imname = [ path img_names{i}];
        im0 = imread(imname);
        imageHandle =imshow(im0);%_____________displays the image
        xlabel(num2str(i));
        set(imageHandle,'ButtonDownFcn',@ImageClickCallback);
    end
end

function coordinates=ImageClickCallback ( objectHandle , eventData )
    axesHandle  = get(objectHandle,'Parent');
    coordinates = get(axesHandle,'CurrentPoint'); 
    coordinates = coordinates(1,1:2);
    message     = sprintf('x: %.1f , y: %.1f',coordinates (1) ,coordinates (2));
    disp(coordinates); %___ add these coordinates for each image
    close(gcf); 
end
```

I want to display a series of images to a user. For each image request input from the user in the form of a mouse click on the image. Store the coordinates of each click in a matrix. Thus, in end having a matrix of dimension `num_images x 2`.

But in the above

a. I can't get the coordinates returned from the function `ImageClickCallback`

b. I am unable to close the image and display a new one whenever the user clicks.

Comment: Try `close(get(axesHandle,'Parent'));`in order to close the image. Are the correct coordinates not displayed?

Comment: @Wauzl Yeah they are displayed but I want to store them also. Last resort creating a global variable and adding. Where to add `close(get(axesHandle,'Parent'));`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have no MATLAB here right now, so there are a couple guesses in my answer. Here we go:

**Closing Figures**

You don't close the image, so it won't close. Just add `close gcf;` at the end of your callback.

**Passing Data**

Now to get the coordinates I'd suggest using the base workspace instead of a global variable, or pass an argument to your callback.
Means I'd use `assignin('base','newcords',coordinates);` at the end of your callback.

Use evalin to get your coordinates back from the base workspace. You can try to access newcords without evalin, however I am pretty sure it isn't going to work.
`newcords=evalin('base','newcords');`

Now you create a new Variable (initialize it outside the for-loop), which holds all coordinates, assuming 2D-coordinates: `allcords=zeros(2,numel(img_name));`

Write the coordinates from the callback into your new-allcords-variable.

```
allcords(1,i)=newcords(1);
allcords(2,i)=newcords(2);
```

On Second thought you don't need to pass the coordinates back from the callback, go with:

Initialize allcords outside your loop:

```
allcords=zeros(2,1);
```

In your callback:

```
allcords=evalin('base',allcords);
allcordssize=size(allcords):

if min(allcordssize)=1
    allcords(1,end)=coordinates(1);
    allcords(2,end)=coordinates(2);
    assignin('base','allcords',allcords);
else
    allcords(1,end+1)=coordinates(1);
    allcords(2,end+1)=coordinates(2);
    assignin('base','allcords',allcords);
end
    close gcf %close picture
```

With that you have all your coordinates from your callback. Another way you could use is, as I mentioned above, passing a variable to your callback.

**Make sure data is matched with correct figure**

The second problem is, your for loop does open all pictures at once I guess? (I Have no MATLAB available). So how about using `uiwait(gcf);` in your `for` loop? (After your `set`). This way you know which coordinates are assigned to which figure (also if all pictures are opened your coordinates are reverse to the img-list-indexes).

P.S.: I'm not sure if `uiwait` works in this case, what would work for sure is if you create a single GUI with just 1 handle (for your image), and instead of closing your figure just redraw your image each time your coordinates are chosen. Or load your GUI each loop-iteration, and pass the image name to the GUI.

Comment: Thanks for reply man! Can you please explain `also if all pictures are opened your coordinates are reverse to the img-list-indexes`.

Comment: @Abhisek Bhatia: If you use figure, you create a new figure which is equal to a new window. When you create a new window it is always on top, which means the figure you created last will be the one on top. If your user selects his coordinates in each window starting with the one on top, the first coordinate-entry will be the one for the last picture, and the last entry the one for the first picture.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Is there some way to clear the current figure and replot the image on the top of it. I don't want to open a new window each time.

Comment: @Abishek Bhatia: Like I said you could try and go with `uiwait(gcf)` However if you are fine with a struct containing your coordinates and the picture name you could try to use: `evalin(strcat('allcords.',get(gcf,'Title')),'base')=coordinates;` or somehting similar.